# How did 'of' absorb so many meanings?

Tags: english, etymology, latin, french

> <sub>[[OED:]](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/130549?rskey=hiUfdJ&result=3&isAdvanced=false#eid) The primary sense was ‘away’, ‘away from’, a sense now obsolete, except in so far as it is retained under the spelling *off* (see off adv., prep., n.1, and adj.). All the existing uses of ***of*** are derivative; many so remote as to retain no trace of the original sense, and so weakened as to be in themselves the expression of relatively indefinable syntactic relationships. [...]</sub>

I already read OED's entire entry of 'Etymology' on OED. Where can I find more information, resources, or studies of ***of***? How might ***of*** have been chosen for these  derivative and so remote uses which retain no trace of the original sense? Surely not randomly?

<sub>See  p 381, *An Introduction to Language* (10 ed, 2014) by Fromkin, Rodman, Hyams: 'As we have shown, linguistic
changes do not happen suddenly. Speakers of English did not wake up one morning and
decide to use the word *beef* for “ox meat," nor do all the children of one particular generation grow up to adopt a new word.</sub>

<sub>PS: I have tried to refine my question per [this](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1667/5306); please advise if it can still be ameliorated. I ask the above here because the OED asserts the influence of Latin's *ab-, de-, ex-* and French's *de-* on ***of***.</sub>

Comment: So you'd be willing to read research on Old English, with examples from Old English?

Comment: @AlexB. Thank you for your comment. Yes, but with 3 caveats: 1. I know nothing of Old English. 2. I shall, but have not yet started to, read textbooks on Historical Linguistics. 3. Ideally, the research should concentrate specifically on ***of***; sadly, I probably lack time to learn all of Old English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a difficult question. Semantic bleaching is a common process in grammaticalization, which it appears 'of' has undergone. But why certain changes are initiated (here, why one word undergoes a change and not another) is the so-called "[actuation problem](http://www.ling.ohio-state.edu/~bjoseph/Viewable611/Lx611BasicIssues.pdf)". It's an ongoing question of historical linguistics. Sorry I don't have a better answer or something more specific to say about 'of'.